# AC voltage on DC voltage

Tags: voltage, biasing

In the voltage divider below, the voltage at point A is obviously 5 V. If we connect a 9 V DC voltage source between ground and point A, the voltage at point A will be 9 V. I think the same is true if an AC voltage source is used. That is because the internal impedance of a voltage source is very low.

Now assume that this voltage divider biases the base of a BJT in simple common emitter amplifier connected to a previous similar stage with a coupling capacitor. Since the output impedance of the previous stage is much lower than the input impedance of the current stage, the previous stage acts as a voltage source. So one may expect that the output of previous stage determines the voltage at point A. But in electronics books we read that the voltage at A is the sum of DC bias voltage and
the AC input voltage. Why is it so?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGUYaf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What's the input impedance of a BJT?

Comment: "But in electronics books we read that the voltage at A is the sum of DC bias voltage and the AC input voltage" - this is a statement that is misleading, at best, when read out of context. They're very likely referring to the [small-signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-signal_model) AC excitation *superimposed* on the DC value. It's not clear how this relates to your inquiry, so perhaps editing the schematic to show the BJT stage you care about might help clear things up.

Comment: The BJT will draw some AC current. Hence the voltage divider is not a perfect voltage divider. The voltage at point A will fluctuate according to the fluctuations of the base current, although this current is small.

Comment: Also remember that a pure voltage source does not exist, this is an approximation we make when we don't care about the "small deviations". Here, we care about these deviations from an ideal voltage source, so we don't do such an approximation. In fact we modelize these deviations as an AC voltage that must be added to the ideal DC voltage source.

Comment: But there are not two voltages at point A that must be added, of course there is only one voltage, which is as I said a DC voltage that fluctuates. The imaginary AC source modelizes these fluctuations around the DC voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a standard *textbook* AC-connected CE BJT stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSsq4f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the capacitors.

Sure, if a low-impedance single-ended signal source were ***directly*** connected (no \$C_{_\text{IN}}\$ used) to the shared node of the biasing pair, \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$, then there's no doubt that the BJT stage's DC biasing would be totally screwed up.

But the reality is that a capacitor is usually applied. \$C_{_\text{IN}}\$ charges up to the average DC difference between the input source and the biasing pair's DC voltage (as also loaded by the emitter.) Since \$C_{_\text{IN}}\$ carries the DC difference, the biasing of the BJT stage is isolated. So the DC biasing of the BJT stage is unaffected. (After, of course, sufficient time has passed to allow \$C_{_\text{IN}}\$ to charge up, appropriately.)

Another way of saying the above is that \$C_{_\text{IN}}\$ provides the necessary DC bias so as to add the necessary DC bias to the AC input signal so that it *rides* correctly (centered) on the stage's DC operating point bias.

(There are *also* DC-connected designs. But that is an entirely different design process and the input for a later stage in the design is entirely determined by the output of a prior stage, which the designer *also* completely controls.)

So the capacitors, as shown, automatically charge up to the differences required. It's that simple.

So, when the textbook says:

> the voltage at A is the sum of DC bias voltage and the AC input
> voltage

That's why.

You just failed to include the input capacitor in your vision of what's being discussed.

Comment: Yes, the capacitor is acting like a DC battery in series with the AC source. I was blind, assuming that it's just a piece of wire! (considering the high frequency of the signal)

Comment: @apadana No problem! It sometimes just takes someone saying so to make it clearer to see. And yes, the capacitor acts very much like a simple DC battery in series with the AC signal. Great way to see it. Keep always in mind that it ***takes time*** for the capacitor to charge up. So upon initial power-up and connection, there is a moment where the capacitor goes through a process of finding the balancing point. But it does do that in the end. Keep up the good questions!

Answer (score 1):

The voltage at any node is the sum of the ac voltage and dc voltage.

It is also true that a voltage source applied to a node will determine the voltage of the node.

Both are correct statements.

Circuit designers must anticipate dc voltage differences between the bias circuitry of a common emitter amplifier and the dc voltage of the previous stage. They must be the same to interconnect.

Capacitive coupling or dc level shifting is often used where the dc voltages must remain different.

Answer (score 1):

A very common way of separating the signal from the bias is to insert a capacitor between stages.  Since the impedance of a capacitor is 1/jωC, its "effect" diminishes as the frequency rises.  If the capacitor is appropriately sized, it will present infinite impedance to the DC bias voltage but will allow the signal to pass with only minor attenuation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl8rdx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
[image: output plot]